# Retrieve photos from Facebook/Instagram

Tags: c#, wpf, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api

I am looking to retrieve photos from Facebook and Instagram for viewing in a WPF application. The idea behind is to show user existing photos and allow them to upload more using C#. A bonus would be to let the user delete photos and set their profile picture, but is not a must.

I cannot find any APIs for either Facebook or Instagram for use in a WPF application, and the ones I did find were all for web (ASP.NET/PHP).

Is there such an API and how might I go about doing this?

Comment: There are no specific APIs for different frameworks – there is _one_ API, and to communicate with it basically all you need is the ability to make HTTP(S) requests from within your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Facebook Graph .NET API.

### Using the Facebook .NET SDK

Here is an example I whipped up, haven't tested. Should work though. It retrieves the profile picture of a user. Though if you read through the APIs you can adapt it for whatever you need.

```
var client = new FacebookClient("accessToken");

object taskResult = await client.GetTaskAsync("/me");
var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)taskResult;
var userId = taskResult.Where(s=>s.Key == "id").First().Value

var profilePicUrl = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture", userId);
```

[Facebook SDK](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/web/getting-started/)

Comment: This answers my Facebook question, but how about Instagram? Thanks for the detailed answer, btw.

Comment: I clearly did not read that part... you could look at: http://instasharp.org/ might be able to help. I don't have knowledge with that though.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they have what you're looking for in the Graph API:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/

Answer (score 0):

For instagram

[This link](https://www.instagram.com/developer/embedding/) will help you embeding the instagram on a simple html webpage.
There is a button on the bottom of the post on instagram.when you click on the link a menu pops up. then click on embed
[image]

now a box pops up

[image]

just copy paste the html and you are done.
it will fetch the post for you